# CodeIgniter Captcha Refuses to Work

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp, captcha

I know there are a trillion similar questions but NONE have been able to help me. Here is the small sample code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Captcha extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){ 

    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $cap_settings = array(
        'word'          => 'Random word',
        'img_path'      => './images/captcha/',
        'img_url'       => base_url().'captcha',
        'font_path'     => './fonts/hardcorium.ttf',
        'img_width'     => '300',
        'img_height'    => '50',
        'expiration'    => 1800
    );

    $cap = create_captcha($cap_settings);

    echo $cap['image'];
}
}
```

**Here's what I know:**

1. Using WAMP localhost
2. The GD2 Library is loaded (php_gd2)
3. I created html links on the controller's index with the same path
   that is shown for the needed files and they work correctly
4. Have used absolute and relative paths
5. The Captcha folder exists, inside the application folder

Nothing is shown and firebugs throws no errors, neither does CI. I have no ideas what could be wrong.

Comment: does the captcha folder exist?

Comment: @tomexsans Yes the folder is inside the application folder.

Comment: use `APPPATH.'/images/captcha';` instead, the error is that it is trying ro find the folder on your root directory.

Comment: @tomexsans I have written it like so: `base_url().'application/images/captcha/'` and still nothing shows.

Comment: `base_url` is for links/URL, links cannot be used as directory path, i'm talking about the `img_path` not the `img_url`

Comment: @tomexsans It works now, how couldn't I think of that ha! Thank you sir you're best create an answer so you get some points.

Comment: @tomexsans I have another questions and thanks a lot for your help. The images generated by the captcha are keep filling the folder how would I go about deleting them?

Comment: a simple solution is that before `create_captcha($cap_settings)` you could delete all files using `delete_files()` http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN! Create an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In the page of view the form must in following manner :-

`<?php echo form_open_multipart(path,'class="form-horizontal"'); ?>`

There must be 777 permission given to captcha folder, so that captcha can we read as well write.You can give permission in following manner:-

Write the below line in terminal

`sudo chmod -R 777 path`

Please check the above two things,as well as check the image path properly.

It will surely help you

Answer (score 0):

1. Create folder captcha on root with permission 777
2. Create font folder on root and place font file in it.
3. $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/'; in config.php

```
class Captcha extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){ 

$this->load->helper('captcha');
$this->load->helper('url');

$cap_settings = array(
    'word'          => 'Random word',
    'img_path'      => './captcha/',
    'img_url'       => base_url().'/captcha/',
    'font_path'     => base_url().'/fonts/hardcorium.ttf',
    'img_width'     => '300',
    'img_height'    => '50',
    'expiration'    => 1800
);

$cap = create_captcha($cap_settings);

echo $cap['image'];
 }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39637942/2107318