# Captcha not working in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wrote a small piece of code which should work for a captcha in Codeigniter. The code should just simply print the time the captcha was created, for a first try. But it doesn't seem to even create the captcha itself. I'm sure the helper is loaded, this is done in the construct function. Next to that, the correct rights for writing the image to a folder should be there. Anyone any idea why it isn't working as it should?

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Register extends CI_Controller{

     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->helper('captcha');
    }

    public function generate_captcha(){
        $vals = array(
            'img_path' => './captcha/',
            'img_url' => base_url().'captcha/',
        );
        echo base_url().'assets/images/captcha/';
        $captcha = create_captcha($vals);

        echo 'cap time: ' . $captcha['time'];

        $captcha_image = $captcha['image'];
        return $captcha_image; 
    }

}
```

**Edit**
Could it have anything to do with something apart from this code? I already set the correct rights to the folder, so it can write images to the directory.

Comment: Comment echo lines and check whether the image has created

Comment: @Lasith Nope it didn't.

Comment: Have you set your base url?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Yes my base_url is correct.

Comment: Are the captcha images being generated and stored, and do they have the correct permissions for the web server to access them?

Comment: @gabe3886 No they are not generated and not stored. When I try to echo anything regarding the captcha, this gives an empty result. The rights should be correct as well.

Comment: @P.Yntema I noticed you do not have the correct path set. You have echoed 'assets/images/captcha/' but not set in code I have updated my answer

Comment: have you enable GD Support  ?

Comment: @P.Yntema What is current output ?? and what is the exact issue of this?

Comment: @Spartan The current output is nothing. It just doesn't display the captcha and the image is not created in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mycaptcha extends CI_Controller  {

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->helper('captcha');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index() { 
        $vals = array(
            'img_path' => './captcha/',
            'img_url' => base_url().'/captcha/',
        );

        $captcha = create_captcha($vals);
        $captcha_image = $captcha['image'];

        print_r($captcha);
    }
}
```

Make sure you have :

1. Create folder captcha on root with permission 777
2. In config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`

Comment: I had the second, but the first one seems to fix the problem. Thanks so much! I had put the rights to 666, which I thought should work out for this. Appearantly not.

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder outside of application called captcha [Captcha Helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html) I think you need also to have more $vals in there as well not just the img_path and img_url

> Also make sure folder  chmod 0777 permissions or 0700

You may need to configure some routes also

```
$route['register/generate_captcha'] = 'register/generate_captcha';
```

Filename: Register.php

```
application

assets > images > captcha // Has the correct permissions

assets > images > captcha > fonts // Has the correct permissions

system

index.php
```

Controller

## Updated

Filename: Register.php   following the [file and class style guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

Set your base url: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`

```
<?php

class Register extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->helper('captcha');
    }

    public function index(){
        $vals = array(
            'word' => 'Random word',
            'img_path' => './assets/images/captcha/',
            'img_url' => base_url('assets/images/captcha'),
            'font_path' => './assets/images/captcha/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width' => '150',
            'img_height' => 30,
            'expiration' => 7200,
            'word_length' => 8,
            'font_size' => 16,
            'img_id' => 'Imageid',
            'pool' => '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
        );

        $cap = create_captcha($vals);
        echo $cap['image'];

    }

}
```

Image Example 1

[image]

Image Example 2

[image]

Comment: Are these fonts required for the captcha? Because I thought I read that they were not.

Comment: I think you can change the fonts that you i tto be by placing them in font folder

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not working for me. It doesn't show any image or whatsoever.

Comment: All that code is copied from the user guide I did not have to do much really Did you change your function to index?

Comment: I noticed you have this `'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha/'` but then you have images/captcha/, so should `'img_url' => base_url().'assets/images/captcha/',` and same with `'img_path' => './assets/images/captcha/',` make sure folder has correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

Location: ***./application/controllers/Captcha.php***

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Captcha extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->driver("session");
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'captcha'));
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', "Name", 'required');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', "Captcha", 'required');
        $userCaptcha = set_value('captcha');
        $word = $this->session->userdata('captchaWord');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE && strcmp(strtoupper($userCaptcha),strtoupper($word)) == 0){

            $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaWord');
            $name = set_value('name');
            $data = array('name' => $name);

            $this->load->view('success-view', $data);

        } else {

            $vals = array('img_path' => 'static/','img_url' => base_url().'static/');
            $captcha = create_captcha($vals);
            $this->session->set_userdata('captchaWord', $captcha['word']);
            $this->load->view('captcha-view', $captcha);
        }
    }
}
```

Location: ***./application/views/captcha-view.php */***

Add a Captcha!

```
<h1>Adding a captcha</h1>

<p>Take a look at <code style="background:rgb(220,220,220);">application/controllers/Captcha.php</code> to look at the controller used to generate the captcha.</p>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open( 'captcha'); ?>
</p>

<p>
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
</p>

<?php echo $image; ?>

<p>
<label for="name">Captcha:</label>
<input id="captcha" name="captcha" type="text" />
</p>

<?php echo form_submit( "submit", "Submit"); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

***Location: ./application/views/success-view.php***

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Success!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Success!</h1>
    <p>Thanks, <?php echo $name; ?>!</p>
</body>

</html>
```